# custom shapes using css3

Tags: css, css-shapes

I need to replicate this module in css:

[image]

I've had a quick go in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WYNP9/16/) however this will not be the way to go. I'm think maybe multiple divs using :before and :after pseudo elements? These also need to be responsive!!

```
<div class="shape">
  <div class="inner">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://www.css3shapes.com/ is a good resource.  You want to use transparent borders.

Comment: What you want to replicate sort of just looks like a bunch of 3d skew transforms.

Comment: @Josiah OK, any chance you could give an example, not done 3d transforms before